# Change values received from database

Tags: java, json, hibernate

I have a JSON file to be generated from this `Graph` class using the GSON library.

This is the code of the class Graph :

```
public class Graph {

    private List<Node> nodes;
    private List<Link> links;

    // Constructors, Getters and Setters


}
```

This is the code of the class Node :

```
public class Node {

    private String name;
    private int group;
    private Set<Link> linksForTarget = new HashSet<Link>(0);
    private Set<Link> linksForSource = new HashSet<Link>(0);

    // Constructors, Getters and Setters


}
```

This is the code of the class Link :

```
public class Link {

    private Integer idLink;
    private Node nodeByTarget;
    private Node nodeBySource;

    // The two above 'nodeByTarget' and 'nodeBySource' 
    // are foreign keys to `Node` class

    // Constructors, Getters and Setters


}
```

This is the JSON file I would like to generate :

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
    {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
    {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":2},
    {"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":2}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0},
    {"source":2,"target":0},
    {"source":3,"target":1},
    {"source":3,"target":2}
  ]
}
```

The problem is that when I get the values from the database and parse them to JSON (using GSON tool) the sources and targets of the links I get are bigger than expected by 1 (since the database's auto-increment never starts with 0) so I get something like this :

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
    {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
    {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine","group":2},
    {"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":2}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":2,"target":1},
    {"source":3,"target":1},
    {"source":4,"target":2},
    {"source":4,"target":3}
  ]
}
```

And that is not working for me!

Now the idea to reduce the values of the sources and targets I get from the database by 1.

I have tried this code :

```
public static List<Link> listLinks() {

    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();

    List<Link> links = session.createQuery("from Link").list();

    List<Link> modLinks = new ArrayList<Link>();
    int oldSource, newSource, oldTarget, newTarget;
    Iterator<Link> itr = links.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        Link l = itr.next();
        oldSource = l.getNodeBySource().getIdNode();
        newSource = oldSource - 1;
        l.getNodeBySource().setIdNode(newSource);
        oldTarget = l.getNodeByTarget().getIdNode();
        newTarget = oldTarget - 1;
        l.getNodeByTarget().setIdNode(newTarget);
        System.out.println(l.getNodeBySource().getIdNode() + " , " + l.getNodeByTarget().getIdNode());
        modLinks.add(l);
    }

    session.close();
    return modLinks;
}
```

But things got even worse since I got negative results!

This is a log result from what I get from all of the data from the database :

```
source : 0 , target : 1
source : -1 , target : 2
source : -2 , target : 3
source : -3 , target : 4
source : -4 , target : 5
source : 0 , target : 1
source : -1 , target : 2
source : -2 , target : 3
source : -3 , target : 4
source : 0 , target : 1
source : -1 , target : 2
source : -2 , target : 3
source : 0 , target : 1
source : -1 , target : 2
source : 0 , target : 1
source : 8 , target : 9
source : 7 , target : 10
source : 8 , target : 9
source : 11 , target : 12
source : 10 , target : 13
source : 9 , target : 14
source : 8 , target : 15
source : 7 , target : 16
source : 11 , target : 12
source : 10 , target : 13
source : 9 , target : 14
source : 8 , target : 15
source : 11 , target : 12
source : 10 , target : 13
source : 9 , target : 14
source : 11 , target : 12
source : 10 , target : 13
source : 11 , target : 12
source : 17 , target : 18
```

What did I do wrong? And how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: First - do you really must start with 0, instead of 1? Second, have you tried modifying the GSON output you receive from the database by decreasing sources and targets by 1, instead of messing around with your database?

Comment: @darioo For the first question, I really have to start by 0 since the resulting JSON will be used to draw a Graph using the D3JS tool and that one starts from 0. For the second question, that idea has crossed my mind and then I thought "Why should I generate a JSON, take it back to modify it and then generate it again?"